# CSS / div with width 100% is a few pixels too high / why?

Tags: css, html, width

I want to build a website that scales to the browsers width.

It all works fine, except that the parent-div containing the 100%-width-divs is always about 5 pixels too high. That gives me huge problems because of the background color (e.g. blue) spilling out at the bottom.

Why is that? And how to solve?
:-)

Kind regards,
Jan

head code:

```
<style type="text/css">

body { background-color:#e7e3d7; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; margin-top:0px; margin-bottom:0px; }    
.banner { width: 100%; }

</style>
```

body code:

```
<div style="background-color:#0000ff;">

<div><img class="banner" src="http://www.janriggert.com/images/footer.png"></div>

</div>
```

Do you see that blue line below the footer? It shouldnt be there...    :-/

Comment: I checked BBEdit & Safari. Can you duplicate the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `max-width:100%` and `display:block` on image.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RyEqK/1/

Comment: Wow! You deserve awesomeness! Thank you so much! :-D

Comment: @SergejPopov the question was "why?" You didn't explain (baseline, inline elements leave room for descender etc)

Comment: @MrLister, The question was not only "why" but also "how to", I didn't know "why", so maybe you can enlighten us with separate answer. I will up-vote.

Comment: @SergejPopov I added the why answer. 8 years later. :)

Comment: @JoshuaDance haha. Nice. As promised - upvoted :D

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to add `display:block` is correct but doesn't cover the why.

`<img>` by default are set to `display: inline;`. Inline-block elements like `<svg>` and `<img>` sit on the text baseline. They are 'in a line' (hence inline) and obey the line rules.

The extra space at the bottom space left to accommodate text characters that drop below the line. They are called descenders and examples are the tail on 'y', 'g' etc.

To remove that extra space, you can add `display: block;` to your `img`.

[This SO answer covers it really well for images with lots of examples.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

[This SO answer covers it well for svgs, which have the same inline default.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626908/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-space-below-svg-in-div-element)