# How to get rid of extra space below svg in div element

Tags: html, css, svg

Here is an illustration of the problem (tested in Firefox and Chrome):

```html
<div style="background-color: red;"><svg height="100px" width="100" style="background-color: blue;"></svg></div>
```

[View on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EXLSF/)

Notice the extra `red` space inside the `div` below the blue `svg`.

Already tried setting `padding` and `margin` of both elements to `0`, but with no luck.

Comment: Seems to be related to a similar problem with images, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7774814/remove-white-space-below-image.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)

Answer (score 291, accepted):

You need `display: block;` on your `svg`.

```
<svg style="display: block;"></svg>
```

This is because inline-block elements (like `<svg>` and `<img>`) sit on the text baseline. The extra space you are seeing is the space left to accommodate character descenders (the tail on 'y', 'g' etc).

You can also use `vertical-align:top` if you need to keep it `inline` or `inline-block`

Comment: Amazing. So do all inline elements add white space at the bottom?

Comment: The explanation is that `inline-block` elements (like `<svg>` and `<img>`) sit on the text baseline. The extra space you are seeing is the space left to accommodate character descenders (the tail on 'y', 'g' etc).

Comment: I would prefer to `vertical-align:top`

Comment: I was convinced the extra space was something to do with `line-height`, but setting `line-height: 0` on the svg and/or its container made no difference. Only `display: block` solved it. This is such a gotcha if you happen to be working on a large SVG because you'd never think of it as inline. If you have a little icon, though, it makes sense.

Comment: `display: block` did not work for me, but `vertical-align` did

Answer (score 17):

`svg` is an `inline` element. `inline` elements leave white-space.

Solution:

Add `display:block` to `svg`, or make height of parent div same as `svg`.

[**DEMO here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/EXLSF/6/)

Answer (score 11):

Another alternative is to add `font-size: 0` to the SVG parent.

Answer (score 5):

Change the `display` property of the svg to be `block`.

Answer (score 2):

simply add height to main div element

```
<div style="background-color: red;height:100px"><svg height="100px" width="100" style="background-color: blue;"></svg></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your style to

style="background-color: red; line-height: 0;"

Answer (score 1):

If you're setting the height on your SVG, and you want the `<a>` tag to wrap around your SVG:

- add `height: fit-content;` to the `<a>`
- add `display: block;` to the SVG

Answer (score 1):

There is an **easy way** to do it. : )

##### `display: flex` will work either. add `display: flex;` in the **`div`** element.

```html
<div style="background-color: red; display: flex; "><svg height="100px" width="100" style="background-color: blue;"></svg></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height:100px` to `div` and using a `height="100%"` on `svg`:

```
<div style="background-color:red;height:100px">
    <svg height="100%" width="100" style="background-color:blue;"></svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. This works fine, but becomes tricky when one does not know the height of the `svg` in advance.