# Button height is greater than the nested content's height

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 alpha.

```
<button class="btn btn-link p-0">
  <div style="display:inline-block; background-color:#c2f5ff; width: 100px; height: 100px;">
  </div>
 </button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x1hphsvb/68/)

I nested a div inside a button. I set height and width on the div. My button width fits the div, but the height of the button is bigger than it needs to be. When you click on the button, the blue outline does not fit the content.

why is this behavior occurring?

Comment: Why do you need a div inside of a button?

Comment: @Toastrackenigma perhaps i want to make an area which has multiple elements clickable

Comment: You are doing that wrong then. **ANY** click on the button will activate scripts on the button parent (unless you properly handle the event), and it is not semantic - try making *more than one button to handle each click event*. If you want to trigger multiple things when clicking on one button, learn how events work in JavaScript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get rid of extra space below svg in div element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626908/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-space-below-svg-in-div-element)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This is due to `inline-block` nature. Inner `div` of button is `inline-block`. Default value of `vertical-align: baseline` which creates extra gap. If you set for you `div` some value of `vertical-align` other than `baseline` (`top`, `middle`, `bottom`) button will have expected `102x102` size (width of content + `1px` borders).

---

Explanation about `vertical-align: baseline` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34952703/1548895):

As browsers by default compute the `vertical-align` property to `baseline`, this is the default behaviour. The following image shows where the baseline is located on text:

[image: Location of the baseline on text]

Baseline aligned elements need to keep space for the [descenders](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descender) that extend below the baseline (like `j`, `p`, `g` etc) as you can see in the above image.

---

So just remove `display: inline-block` from your inner `div` to see expected result.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `display: inline-block` on the div inside the btn and remove the border of the btn `border: none` (to remove the white padding inside the btn). So now the div inside is automatically `display: block`

Hope this help :)

Comment: Div elements are displayed as block level elements in all browsers by default anyway

Answer (score 0):

Simply, the button is not `100px` wide or high.

You need to set the size of the button, *then* make the div inside fill the button.

```css
body {
    margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button class="btn btn-link p-0" style="border-style:none;width:100px;height:100px;">
  <div style="background-color:#c2f5ff; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
  </div>
 </button>
```

We do this by setting `width:100px` and `height:100px` on the button itself, and then making the div inside fill the available width and height with `width:100%` and `height:100%`.

There is also a `1px`-wide border around the button which you should remove with `border-style:none`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would want a div inside a button, but this is what I did:

I set `width` and `height` to the button and set `width` and `height` of the nested div to `100%`. That will make the nested div the same size as the button.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/08zd9xo5/).