# Button containing SVG is of unexpected height

Tags: css

I have this markup:

```
<p style="background-color: #000">
    <button>
        <svg width="25px" height="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 43.42 43.42">
            <path d="M21.71,43.42A21.71,21.71,0,1,1,43.42,21.71,21.73,21.73,0,0,1,21.71,43.42ZM21.71,2A19.71,19.71,0,1,0,41.42,21.71,19.73,19.73,0,0,0,21.71,2Z" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
</p>
```

I want the button to be no larger than the 25x25 SVG it contains.

```
button {
  background: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

The width of the button is correct, but the computed height is 28px, and I can't figure out where the 3 extra pixels are coming from.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oyrRbM

Comment: If you add `line-height: 0` to the `<p>` the 3 extra pixels go away.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Button height is greater than the nested content's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45423874/button-height-is-greater-than-the-nested-contents-height)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
button {
  background: transparent;
  border-width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  line-height:0px
}
```

```html
<p style="background-color: #000">
    <button>
        <svg width="25px" height="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" viewBox="0 0 43.42 43.42">
            <path d="M21.71,43.42A21.71,21.71,0,1,1,43.42,21.71,21.73,21.73,0,0,1,21.71,43.42ZM21.71,2A19.71,19.71,0,1,0,41.42,21.71,19.73,19.73,0,0,0,21.71,2Z" style="fill: rgb(255, 255, 255);"></path>
        </svg>
    </button>
```

Comment: Which browser did you test that in? It doesn't work for me in IE11, Edge, or Firefox on Windows 10. Also, a unitless number is the [preferred way](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height) to set line-height.

Comment: what if you give the button a height 25px

Answer (score 8):

SVGs are inline-block elements by default, which means they have extra space to accomodate character descenders (y and g "legs" for example).

You should be able to get the desired behaviour by changing the SVG to `display: block`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45424887/823732) answer's illustration.