# Why is my containing span larger than my svg?

Tags: html, css

I have an `svg` that is wrapped in a `span`.  The `svg` has a set `height` and `width` of `15px`.

```
<span>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" id="remove-circle" viewBox="0 0 1200 1200.0071" width="15px" height="15px"><path d="..."/></svg>
</span>
```

I wrap the `svg` in a `span` so I can more easily position it, but it then has a `height` of `19px`.  I have tried setting the `line-height` to `0`, but that didn't change anything.  What do I need to do to make the `span` the same size as the `svg`?

Comment: are there any other classes in your CSS that might be at play?

Comment: `<span style="height:15px;">`

Comment: It is a react component using CSS modules so there shouldn't be anything messing with the CSS

Comment: does this fix it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626908/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-space-below-svg-in-div-element

Comment: @JM-AGMS it will still add 2px to the height... looks like a different issue as mentioned in the comment above

Comment: Try `<span style='height:15px; display:table`>...` or `table-cell`, or simply `inline-block` maybe.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I was able to reproduce this locally and fixed it by applying the following CSS to the surrounding `<span>`

```
span {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why this is?