# svg inside scroll div has a bottom gutter

Tags: html, css, svg

```css
 .wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
}

.inner {
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg class="inner"></svg>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

see the demo above.

when scroll to the bottom, there is a red gutter which is the background of `wrapper` in case 1 and case 2 works fine.

Does anyone knows why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

The SVG is an image, so it behaves like any `<image>` and sits on the text baseline.  So the space you are seeing is the space left below the text baseline for descenders etc.

To fix, just make the SVG `display: block`.

The second version works fine because `<div>`s are already `display: block`.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: red;
}

.inner {
    display: block;
    width: 300px;
    height: 150px;
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
    <svg class="inner"></svg>
</div>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks a lot, that helps

Answer (score 0):

seems duplicate with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626908/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-space-below-svg-in-div-element)

add `display: block;` to the svg element could solve the problem