# remove default space while convert svg to png

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, svg

I convert SVG to png using `domtoimage.js` and it works fine but it put some default blank space at the bottom of the image below is my code in laravel.

**view code**

```
<div class="svg-class" id="svg-class" style="height: 192px; width:192px;">
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="192" height="192" viewBox="0 0 192 192">
        <path fill="%239C92AC" class="inner" fill-opacity="1" d="M192 15v2a11 11 0 0 0-11 11c0 1.94 1.16 4.75 2.53 6.11l2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 1.22 7.56l-.43.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66 4.13H145v35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 3.03 4.87l.84.43c1.58.79 4 .4 5.24-.85l2.36-2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 7.51-3.11 13 13 0 1 1 .02 26 12 12 0 0 1-7.53-3.11l-2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0-5.24-.85l-.84.43a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-3.03 4.87V143h35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66 4.13l.43.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-1.22 7.56l-2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 181 164a11 11 0 0 0 11 11v2a13 13 0 0 1-13-13 12 12 0 0 1 3.11-7.53l2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0 .85-5.24l-.43-.84a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-4.87-3.03H145v35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13 6.66l-.84.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-7.56-1.22l-2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 124 181a11 11 0 0 0-11 11h-2a13 13 0 0 1 13-13c2.47 0 5.79 1.37 7.53 3.11l2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0 5.24.85l.84-.43a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 3.03-4.87V145h-35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66-4.13l-.43-.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 1.22-7.56l2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 107 124a11 11 0 0 0-22 0c0 1.94 1.16 4.75 2.53 6.11l2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 1.22 7.56l-.43.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66 4.13H49v35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 3.03 4.87l.84.43c1.58.79 4 .4 5.24-.85l2.36-2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 7.51-3.11A13 13 0 0 1 81 192h-2a11 11 0 0 0-11-11c-1.94 0-4.75 1.16-6.11 2.53l-2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-7.56 1.22l-.84-.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13-6.66V145H11.98a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-4.87 3.03l-.43.84c-.79 1.58-.4 4 .85 5.24l2.36 2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 3.11 7.51A13 13 0 0 1 0 177v-2a11 11 0 0 0 11-11c0-1.94-1.16-4.75-2.53-6.11l-2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-1.22-7.56l.43-.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66-4.13H47v-35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-3.03-4.87l-.84-.43c-1.59-.8-4-.4-5.24.85l-2.36 2.36A12 12 0 0 1 28 109a13 13 0 1 1 0-26c2.47 0 5.79 1.37 7.53 3.11l2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0 5.24.85l.84-.43A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 47 84.02V49H11.98a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-6.66-4.13l-.43-.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 1.22-7.56l2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 11 28 11 11 0 0 0 0 17v-2a13 13 0 0 1 13 13c0 2.47-1.37 5.79-3.11 7.53l-2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0-.85 5.24l.43.84A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 11.98 47H47V11.98a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13-6.66l.84-.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 7.56 1.22l2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 68 11 11 11 0 0 0 79 0h2a13 13 0 0 1-13 13 12 12 0 0 1-7.53-3.11l-2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0-5.24-.85l-.84.43A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 49 11.98V47h35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66 4.13l.43.84a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-1.22 7.56l-2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 85 68a11 11 0 0 0 22 0c0-1.94-1.16-4.75-2.53-6.11l-2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-1.22-7.56l.43-.84a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 6.66-4.13H143V11.98a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-3.03-4.87l-.84-.43c-1.59-.8-4-.4-5.24.85l-2.36 2.36A12 12 0 0 1 124 13a13 13 0 0 1-13-13h2a11 11 0 0 0 11 11c1.94 0 4.75-1.16 6.11-2.53l2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 7.56-1.22l.84.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13 6.66V47h35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 4.87-3.03l.43-.84c.8-1.59.4-4-.85-5.24l-2.36-2.36A12 12 0 0 1 179 28a13 13 0 0 1 13-13zM84.02 143a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 4.87-3.03l.43-.84c.8-1.59.4-4-.85-5.24l-2.36-2.36A12 12 0 0 1 83 124a13 13 0 1 1 26 0c0 2.47-1.37 5.79-3.11 7.53l-2.36 2.36a4.94 4.94 0 0 0-.85 5.24l.43.84a6.1 6.1 0 0 0 4.87 3.03H143v-35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13-6.66l.84-.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1 7.56 1.22l2.36 2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 164 107a11 11 0 0 0 0-22c-1.94 0-4.75 1.16-6.11 2.53l-2.36 2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1-7.56 1.22l-.84-.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13-6.66V49h-35.02a6.1 6.1 0 0 0-4.87 3.03l-.43.84c-.79 1.58-.4 4 .85 5.24l2.36 2.36a12.04 12.04 0 0 1 3.11 7.51A13 13 0 1 1 83 68a12 12 0 0 1 3.11-7.53l2.36-2.36a4.93 4.93 0 0 0 .85-5.24l-.43-.84A6.1 6.1 0 0 0 84.02 49H49v35.02a8.08 8.08 0 0 1-4.13 6.66l-.84.43a6.91 6.91 0 0 1-7.56-1.22l-2.36-2.36A10.06 10.06 0 0 0 28 85a11 11 0 0 0 0 22c1.94 0 4.75-1.16 6.11-2.53l2.36-2.36a6.93 6.93 0 0 1 7.56-1.22l.84.43a8.08 8.08 0 0 1 4.13 6.66V143h35.02z"></path>
    </svg>
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="exportImage">Submit</button>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#exportImage').click(function(){
        domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('svg-class'), { quality: 1 })
        .then(function (dataUrl) {
            $.ajax({
                url:"{{ url('saveimg') }}",
                type:"post",
                data:{'imgsrc':dataUrl , "_token":"{{ csrf_token() }}"},
                success:function(data){
                     console.log('sucess');
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

**controller code**

```
public function saveimg(Request $request)
{
    $imageData=$request->imgsrc;
    $filteredData=substr($imageData, strpos($imageData, ",")+1);
    $unencodedData=base64_decode($filteredData);
    $fp = fopen( 'saved_img/test1.png', 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $unencodedData);
    fclose( $fp );
    return true;
}
```

above code generates png from SVG with some blank space at bottom of the image that I attached an image of blank space, how can I remove that space from the bottom.

[image: blank space at bottom of image around 3px]

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626908/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-space-below-svg-in-div-element/24626988

Comment: If you want to export just the SVG, why are you asking it to convert the `<div>` ?  Try passing the `<svg>` to that library instead.