# HTML+CSS height/margin/border/padding not adding up

Tags: html, css, height, overflow, margin

Greetings Stackoverflow!

I have problems pixel-perfect setting my tags. Here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/NLbyag

My aim is to have my `<svg>` and `<table id="time-h-axis">` tags horizontally scrollable inside their `<div id="main-charts">` parent, but not vertically.
`<svg>` and `<table id="time-h-axis">` have height 330 and 70 which makes the 400px height of `<div id="main-charts">`.

However, there are a few extra vertical pixels coming from somewhere (one can scroll vertically and see a bit of lightgreen of the div in the codepen)...
I am out of ideas... Help needed! Thanks ;-)

HTML:

```
<div id="main-charts">            
  <table id="time-h-axis"><tr></tr></table>
  <svg height="330" width="11970"></svg>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#main-charts {
  width:1000px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;

}

#time-h-axis {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 11970px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: violet;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#main-charts svg {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the SVG to `display:block` (per this [**SO Q&A**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24626908/how-to-get-rid-of-extra-space-below-svg-in-div-element)) and the wrapper to `overflow:auto`

```css
#main-charts {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  overflow: auto;
}

#time-h-axis {
  border-spacing: 0px;
  width: 11970px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: violet;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

#main-charts svg {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="main-charts">
  <table id="time-h-axis">
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
  <svg height="330" width="11970"></svg>
</div>
```

[**Codepen Demo**](https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/KxNopG)