# HTML5 Video container slightly larger than video

Tags: css, html, video

I have an html5 video header that works as expected with only one problem, the container is about 4 pixels taller than the video. It wouldn't be such a problem except the container has an inset shadow covering the video that also extends slightly below the video and it doesn't look good.

I read somewhere setting `display: inline-block` on the parent div makes it only expand as large as it's children but that didn't change anything when I tried.

**CSS**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}
body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.vidContainer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.vidShadow {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 500px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 500px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 500px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="vidContainer">
  <video loop autoplay>
      <source src="media/headerVideo.webm" type="video/webm">
      <source src="media/headerVideo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  </video>
  <div class="vidShadow"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Please try this:

```
video {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
}
```

Comment: Excellent, that worked. Thank you. Can you tell me why this works? I have used flex box before but I just don't see what it is doing here.

Comment: Flex layout so items 'have equal height'

Comment: I searched for hours to find this! In my case I had a video element in a flexbox container and the height of the container was about 10px too large (larger than the only child, the video element) in Firefox and Chrome. Video had no controls. This was the only solution.
I would like to know why this works as well. Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

To those wondering why setting it to anything other than `inline` or `inline-block` solves it miraculously, it has to do with how the browser allocates vertical space for inline elements. This issue arises more commonly on images and svgs, which is why most of the correct the explanations have been made on those questions:

- [Image inside div has extra space below the image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image)
- [CSS / div with width 100% is a few pixels too high / why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16495831/css-div-with-width-100-is-a-few-pixels-too-high-why)